# onkeyup event stops onchange ajax event from firing

Tags: javascript, ajax

So I have a an AJAX call on the onchange event of a text box and a very simple mask function (to add dashes to an SSN) on the onkeyup event.  Both of these functions work fine on thier own, however, if the mask inserts a dash and then i move off the text box, the onchange event will not fire.

Anyone have any ideas of why?  My guess is that by changing the value with the mask function, the text box no longer thinks anything has changed.

Thanks

```
SSN: <input id="SSN" maxlength="11" size="8" onchange="validateSSN();" onkeyup="mask()">
<span id="SSNnote"></span>

<script type="text/javascript">

function validateSSN(){
    var cfc = new myajax();
    cfc.setCallbackHandler(function(AjaxResults) {UpdateValidationNotes('SSNnote', AjaxResults);});
    cfc.ValidateSSN(document.getElementById("SSN").value);
}

function mask(){

    var temp = document.getElementById("#WhichName#").value;
    var e = window.event;
    if (e.keyCode == 189){

        document.getElementById("SSN").value = temp.substring(0,temp.length-1);
        return false;
    }

    if ( temp.length == 3 || temp.length == 6)
        if (e.keyCode != 8)
            document.getElementById("SSN").value = document.getElementById("SSN").value + '-';

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you are right, the `onchange` won't fire if you change the value of the box using javascript. So you need to call the `validateSSN()` manually inside your `mask`-function.

Comment: After I read your answer, the rusty gears in my head started grinding and I remember an issues like this before. I can't call my validateSSN() in my mask function, cause my AJAX displays messages, and I only want it to display when they leave the field. So, a quick change from onchange to onblur solved the problem! Not sure why I didn't think of that before, I guess just to much rust.... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript Function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function mask(str, textbox, loc, delim) {      
    var locs = loc.split(',');

    for (var i = 0; i <= locs.length; i++) {
      for (var k = 0; k <= str.length; k++) {
        if (k == locs[i]) {
            if (str.substring(k, k + 1) != delim) {
                str = str.substring(0, k) + delim + str.substring(k, str.length)
            }
        }
      }
    }
    textbox.value = str
  }
</script>
```

Write this Code in body Tag:

```
<label class="label">Social Security Number: *</label>
<input type="text" size="15" name="social_security_number" class="input"
    id="txtsocial_security_number"  runat="server" 
    onKeyUp="javascript:return mask(this.value,this,'3,6','-');"
    onBlur="javascript:return mask(this.value,this,'3,6','-');" maxlength="11">
```

This will result in this format: 797-97-9797